# Javascript not working on all Heroku pages

Tags: javascript, ajax, heroku

I have a Rails 4 app that I am deploying to Heroku.  The asset pipeline seems to be doing its job and minifying the js file.  Everything works fine in development.  After I push to Heroku, the js file will only work on certain pages.  I am doing a the same AJAX PUT on multiple pages, and on some pages it works fine, other pages I get a 404 error.

`PUT http://thawing-thicket-4506.herokuapp.com/scouts/1/reqs 404 (Not Found)`

Here is the filename: `application-5f31b026bf954dbd536069113d4c4345.js` and the version appears to be the same for both pages using the file.

What could be the cause of this?  Any help would be great. Please ask for any other info that would be helpful.

Comment: For that example URL you have above, what does the relevant route look like in `config/routes.rb`? What does the ERB markup for the form/link to that particular action look like? I ask because resource definitions in Rails 4 now use the `PATCH` method and not the `PUT` method.

Answer (score 0):

I had some data-attributes messed up.  It was erroring out on the server and returning a 404.  I started to get the same error in my dev environment and was able to follow the stack trace.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: This is just a tip, but you can check your Heroku logs with the `heroku logs` command (you can even tail them with `heroku logs --tail`. While I get that you may not want to do this all the time, it will log errors that occur in your application the same way that it does on your local/dev machine